# How do I test Google Adsense targeted for Canada when I'm in the US?

Tags: adsense

I am setting up targeting for our networks, and would like Canadian clients to have specific targeted ads, which Google bases off of IP address.

I, however, am in the States, and don't know how I can test this.

Is anyone aware of a solution?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: It's still an interesting question for the programming community.

Answer (score 6):

### AdSense Preview Tool

To test AdSense ads targetted for a geographical region outside of your current region, you need to download and install the [AdSense Preview Tool](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10005&topic=160) (it is actually a registry setting.  I believe you also need to have the Google Toolbar installed).

- [Google AdSense Preview Tool](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10005&topic=160)

Information about the preview tool *(including how to preview ads targetted for other geographical regions)* can be found here:
https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/topic.py?topic=160

**A couple of third party web based tools:**

- [AdSense Sandbox 1.0](http://www.labnol.org/google-adsense-sandbox/)
- [Khrido AdSense Tool](http://tools.khrido.com/webtools/google-adsense-preview.aspx)

---

### AdWords Preview Tool

To preview AdWords ads targetted for other geographical regions, log into your Google Adwords account (adwords.goolge.com), and then do the following:

**Tools > Ads Preview Tool**

Enter your **keyword**, select **Google.ca** as your domain, Country as **Canada**, and click the **Preview Ad** button.

Here is the direct url you can use (this is for the search query "Stack Overflow"):
http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&host=google.ca&q=stack%20overflow&adtest=on&gl=CA&gr=&gcs=

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try finding a proxy server that resides in Canada.

A proxy server, is a server that you connect to. It sits between you and any sites you want to visit. So when say Google gets a request, it'll see the IP of the proxy (which is Canadian), and not your US IP address.

I found this site, but I havn't tested it out yet, but give it a try if you wish:
[Free Canadian Proxy](http://www.freeproxy.ca/). They have three [Canadian proxies](http://www.freeproxy.ca/Filter~38~~.html).

Answer (score 0):

[A free proxy](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=free+proxy) to view the site if the site is available outside of your network. Just set your browser proxy to a Canadian one. If you're behind a proxy already it'll be a pain though.

**Update:** in fact there is a [Canadian one](http://www.freeproxy.ca/) #3 on that list!